# An elegant formulation for typed sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, type-theory

Fix a poset $T$, which we'll think of as a set of "types," interpreting $a \leq b$ as "$a$ is more general than $b$." Construct a category of TSet as follows.

**Objects:** Pairs ($X$, $\tau : X \rightarrow T$)
**Arrows:** Functions $f : X \rightarrow Y$ that respect type subsumption, i.e. $\tau(x) \leq \sigma(f(x))$

In the case where $T$ is a suitably nice poset (e.g. a frame, distributive lattice, cHA, ...), is there a slick formulation for such a category which makes it clear which (co)limits are hanging around and what properties they have?

Comment: Do you mean "**Arrows**: Functions $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y,\sigma)$ that respect type subsumption, i.e. $\tau(x)\leq\tau(y)\ \Rightarrow\ \sigma(f(x))\leq\sigma(f(y))$"? Or perhaps I have misunderstood the goal. 

Comment: If that *is* what you meant, it would mean a sort of "Equilogical Spaces (http://andrej.com/papers/equ-paper.pdf) with subtyping", which would be quite interesting.

Comment: Interesting stuff! It seems quite different from my original intention however, which was to define a category of sets relative to a (fixed) type system and think of a function as a kind of "matching". I.e. for x to be mapped on to f(x), its type must be more general than the type of f(x).

Comment: What I have in mind is reasoning about rewrite systems on algebraic structures whose constituents might have types. In its own right, the category T-Set is not that interesting, but consider e.g. the category of graphs that have a typed set of vertices rather than a set. Then the ordering on T plays the role of the type-unification step on the vertices when matching the LHS of a rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "type"?

Comment: In this case, by type I mean "an element of a poset". Perhaps a better term for it would be "unifiable data", since examples I have in mind are things like expressions with free variables, with "s <= t" interpreted as "there exists a substitution of free variables that turns s into t".